# can begin transaction in hibernate called while commiting/rollback

Tags: java, hibernate

Will the below code works fine or do I need to begin transaction before doing work.

```java
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();

//do some work like session.save/Update

finally{
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: session.save/session.update needs to be done after starting a transaction.

Comment: But when I tested the above code, it worked fine , I mean the data got commited. But what I dont understand is the real purpose of begining transaction before doing any work with session.

Answer (score 4):

No. Of course the code being part of the transaction must be between the begin and the commit of the transaction.

Here(s what [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged) says:

> The session/transaction handling idiom looks like this:

```
// Non-managed environment idiom
Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();

    // do some work
    ...

    tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you need to manage transaction, commit for getting immediate effect and any exceptions thrown by Hibernate are FATAL, you have to roll back the transaction and close the current session.